# How can I merge multiple cells back into one?

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad

I need to take content from an Excel spreadsheet (see below for example), that takes up about 20 cells, and paste it into one cell. I've tried pasting it into Word or notepad documents, and then pasting it back, but it still tries to import it back in tab delimited format (taking up the 20 cells again).

I need to turn this:

```
Title:  Farmers Eating
Year:   1980
Categories: Bulls
    Prairies
    Shepherds
    Farmers
Geographical Area:  Midwest, South
```

Into this:

```
Title:Farmers Eating Year:1980 Categories:Bulls Prairies Shepherds Farmers Geographical Area:Midwest, South
```

So that it fits back into one cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that, when you paste into Microsoft Word, you paste as unformatted text only. 
If so, it seems that the next step is to fire up a “Find and Replace” window (available by keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and replace all occurrences of `^p` (the symbol for an end-of-paragraph) with spaces.  (Then copy and paste back into Excel.)

Comment: +1.  Depending upon the formating that your fields come with, you may have to replace the delimiting characters (e.g. tabs) as well.